# How to recieve and parse data coming from a Python socket server in dart?

Tags: python, flutter, dart, sockets, bytestream

I have a socket server running in Python that sends a byte stream through the socket in which, the first 8 bytes contain the size of the remaining message body. The code looks something like this:

```
    data_to_send = struct.pack("Q", len(pickle_dump))+pickle_dump
    
    client_socket.sendall(data_to_send)
```

The client endpoint of this, that is written in Python looks like this:

```
data = b''
PAYLOAD_SIZE = struct.calcsize('Q')

while len(data) < PAYLOAD_SIZE:
    packet = client_socket.recv(1024)
    if not packet:
        break
    data += packet

    print(len(data), PAYLOAD_SIZE)

packed_msg_size = struct.unpack('Q', data[:PAYLOAD_SIZE])[0]
data = data[PAYLOAD_SIZE:]

while len(data) < packed_msg_size:
    data += client_socket.recv(1024)

print(type(data))
frame_data = data[:packed_msg_size]
data = data[packed_msg_size:]
```

Now I am kind of new to ***dart*** and ***flutter***. So I kind of tried recieving the packets through dart's sockets (which I am not sure how it is implemented) like this:

```
Socket.connect("10.0.2.2", 7878).then((socket) {
        SOCKET = socket;

        setState(() {
          print('Connected to: '
              '${socket.remoteAddress.address}:${socket.remotePort}');
          log = '${socket.remoteAddress.address}:${socket.remotePort}';
        });

        var FULL_CLUSTER = ByteData(0);


        // MAIN STUFF STARTS HERE
        socket.listen((data) {
          Uint8List size_bytesdata = data.sublist(0, 8);
          print(size_bytesdata.buffer.asByteData().getUint64(0)); // Prints -6552722064661282816
          print(size_bytesdata);
          socket.destroy();
        });
        //

      }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
        setState(() {
          log = '$error\n\n$stackTrace';
        });
      });
```

Now first of all, I figured out that Dart's sockets shows bytes in Uint8List format, so I tried doing what I did in the python client script, but the values do not match.

The `len(pickle_dump)` has the value *921765* but the dart code(as mentioned in the snippet) prints *-6552722064661282816*. Now I believe the type recognition by dart is what's causing the trouble as I have packed is as `'Q'` (using struct) in the Server script, which stands for *'Unsigned long long'* but, in dart, I parsed it as *'Unsigned int'*. How do I solve this issue? Also, a brief discussion what's exactly going will help a lot.

Comment: change the default `endian` in `getUint64(0)`

Comment: If you are going to be reading arbitrary lumps of data from a stream, you will find this class particularly useful: https://pub.dev/documentation/buffer/latest/buffer/ByteDataReader-class.html Your `listen` just dumps the data on the end and you can read all sorts of data types from the front.

Comment: I mean, the funtion `getUint64(0)` is literally supposed to print an Unsigned int, but it's printing a negative value, i.e., *-6552722064661282816*

What is going on?

Comment: Edit: I figured it out. The problem is that the endianness needs to be little in this case, i.e., `getUint64(0, Endian.little)`. I think it's got something to do with struct's packing, I'm not sure, I will post a detailed solution after I get a grasp of what is actually happening as a whole.

Comment: check https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html - they say: "Alternatively, the first character of the format string can be used to indicate the byte order, size and alignment of the packed data, according to the following table" - I would use `!` prefix to be sure that always the same order is used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink), the problem here is caused because the default Endian of Dart's `getUint64()` is different than that of Python's **struct** library (which uses the 'little' endianness to pack data). So just rewritting the line from`getUint64(0)` to `getUint64(0, Endian.little)` fixes the problem in this case.